# Cannot make my input bar case-insensitive for my user callback

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm using dash plotly in my application. Part of my application has an multi-input bar, where users can quickly search for a value and select them. The only problem is, the input bar is case-sensitive. Users searching for `nflx` and `NFLX` will get two different results, with only one of them being correct and working. I need both values to match.

I managed to solve the issue for only the the first value inputted by the user! Only the first value inputted by the user is case-insensitive by design because of my function. Because my input `value` can sometimes be one value (a string) or a multi-value (list), I'm struggling trying to implement case insensitivity for ALL values inputted and delivered through the callback

I need to remove this ASAP and I've been trying to figure out how to using Dash's callback (based off Flasks callback).

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output("dynamic-dropdown", "options"),
    [dash.dependencies.Input("dynamic-dropdown", "search_value")],
    [dash.dependencies.State("dynamic-dropdown", "value")],
)
def update_multi_options(search_value, value):
    if search_value is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    elif search_value is True:
        search_value.upper()

    elif value is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    elif search_value is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    elif value is list:
        [x.upper() for x in value]
        [x.upper() for x in search_value]
        
        return [
            o for o in OPTIONS if search_value in o["label"] or o["value"] in (value.upper() if value else [])
        ]
    else:
    # Make sure that the set values are in the option list, else they will disappear
    # from the shown select list, but still part of the `value`.
        [x.upper() for x in value]
        [x.upper() for x in search_value]
        return [
            o for o in OPTIONS if search_value in o["label"] or o["value"] in (value or [])
        ]
```

Yes I overkilled it during de-bugging, trying to find my errors. The goal is trying to play with `value` and `search_value`. There isn't a one simple function to do this, because lists have no attribute to `.upper()`

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

I do not get any TraceBack errors with this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to fix the issue below:

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output("dynamic-dropdown", "options"),
    [dash.dependencies.Input("dynamic-dropdown", "search_value")],
    [dash.dependencies.State("dynamic-dropdown", "value")],
)
def update_multi_options(search_value, value):
    if search_value is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
    # Make sure that the set values are in the option list, else they will disappear
    # from the shown select list, but still part of the `value`.
        return [
            o for o in OPTIONS if search_value.upper() in o["label"].upper() or o["value"] in (value or [])
        ]
```

You have to only focus on `search_value` and `o["label"]` for adding `upper()`.